# Is it possible to host a website in godaddy server and Database in Amazon AWS MySQL RDS?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, dbconnection

I am using GoDaddy VPS server for over an year, now i am planning to migrate to AWS, go i have got GoDaddy VPS server with validity until next 5 years. i have a website hosted in AWS also, its very very fast compared to the site hosted in GoDaddy. I think the problem is the big database. So i thought of creating a AWS RDS MySQL database and use that particular database to the site hosted in GoDaddy. But i don't have any idea of how to establish the connection. If it is possible kindly anyone give me some tips. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can connect to an Amazon RDS instance from outside the AWS network (note: when you create the database you can specify whether it is publicly accessible or accessible from the VPC only)

Of course, the bandwidth and latency will be worse compared to an EC2 located in the same region as the RDS server.

So I don't think this will solve your performance problems. It does offload the database management (backup/restore/monitoring) to AWS which is very useful for a production system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have checked with publicly accessible also but still i a getting timedout error.

Comment: Check the RDS security groups. It may be configured to reject some connections. Try connecting with the mysql command line tool `mysql -h hostname`